# Conversion from rgb-integer to byte array and back does not work

Tags: java, image, rgba

I try to save data in images by manipulating the rgb bytes. But every time the conversion rgb-byte[] and back does not return the same value. Afer using own methods with bit shifting I used the Java Color class, but there seems to be a bug with the alpha channel.
The following test method works fine for the color values, but the alpha value is different every time.

```
Random r = new Random();
int red = r.nextInt(255), green = r.nextInt(255), blue = r.nextInt(255), alpha = r.nextInt(255); 
Color one = new Color(red, green, blue, alpha);
Color two = new Color(one.getRGB());
System.out.println(one.getRed() + " " + one.getGreen() + " " + one.getBlue() + " " + one.getAlpha());
System.out.println(two.getRed() + " " + two.getGreen() + " " + two.getBlue() + " " + two.getAlpha());
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in Java?

Answer (score 0):

the single-argument `Color` constructor ignores alpha.  Use the two-arg constructor:

```
Color two = new Color(one.getRGB(), true);
```